# nHaving Issues When Salesforce Mobile SDK 2.1 App Upgraded to Salesforce Mobile SDK 3.0 on iOS

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

We have a mobile application which has been developed using Salesforce Mobile SDK 2.1 and Backbone.JS (Smartstore + smartsync) on iOS platform and we recently, move it to Salesforce Mobile SDK 3.0.

We en-counted some issues, specially with addEventListener event where it didn't work which works fine with SDK 2.1.

**document**.addEventListener("offline", function () {}

**document**.addEventListener("online", function () {}

But somehow, once we changed to **window** from **document** as below it triggers the listeners but both firing at the same time and when the application comes online it fires twice each

**window**.addEventListener("offline", function () {}

**window**.addEventListener("online", function () {}

Offline Tracker Code :

```
        app.models.OfflineTracker = Backbone.Model.extend({
              initialize: function () { 
                  var that = this;
                  this.set("isOnline", navigator.onLine);
                  //start here
                  document.addEventListener("offline", function () {
                      debugLog("Received OFFLINE event");

                      that.set("isOnline", false);

                      app.router.navigate('#getUserLanguage', true);
                  }, false);
                  document.addEventListener("online", function () {
                      debugLog("Received ONLINE event");

                      that.set("isOnline", true);

                      app.router.navigate('#home', true);

                  }, false);
              }
          });
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you see this issue on iOS/ Android or both?

Comment: It's a in-house application runs on iOS platform.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using window.addEventListener, I'm curious why you upgraded to 3.0 and not 3.1? Do you mind your sharing your code snippet?

Comment: Well this upgrade was done couple of month earlier before 3.1 launch. I'll update the offline tracker code snippet along with the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Akhilesh Gupta: Found the solution for this issue where we need to add the **org.apache.cordova.network-information** cordova plugin to listen for online/offline events.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're refering to [this](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/mobile_sdk/Content/samples_account_editor.htm) hybrid example from Mobile SDK. This looks like a scenario where network detection is not working because of a missed plugin/ missing step. If you are upgrading your app from Mobile SDK 2.x to 3.0, you should be following these commands

```
npm install cordova -g

cordova create TestApp
cd TestApp
cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios
cordova prepare
```

If this does not help, try moving the listeners to ondeviceready() as shown below

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    document.addEventListener("offline", app.onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", app.onOnline, false);
},

onOnline:function(){
    console.log("Online");
}
onOffline: function(){
    console.log("Offline");
}
```

Comment: Thank you but above solutions didn't work and we cloned the https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS and tried the AccountEditor project which has the OfflineTracker code same as our code. But it also having the same issue where once we once we changed to window from document it works but fired twice. Not sure whether it is something to do with the xcode (version 6.1 OS X version 10.9.5)?

Comment: Interesting, did you clone 3.1? If the issue is reproducible on 3.1, I would recommend you post it Mobile SDK Google+ community page to confirm if this is a bug - https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/114225252149514546445

Comment: Ok thanks for your attention on this we have posted it there: https://plus.google.com/114847257470080569874/posts/6PpdcFurpL9